# Sql Server - Encoding issue, replace strange characters

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, encoding, character-encoding

After importing some data into a Sql 2014 database, I realized that there are some fields in which the data replaced German characters such as (ü, ß, ä, ö, etc) with some weird characters. Ex.

```
MÃ¼nchen should be München
ChiemgaustraÃe should be Chiemgaustraße
KÃ¶nigstr should be Königstr
```

I would like to replace these characters with the right German letter. Ex.

```
Ã¼ -> ü
Ã - > ß
Ã¶ -> ö
```

However when I run queries like the following to try to identify which rows have these characters, the queries returns 0 rows.

```
select      address
from        Directory
where       street like N'%ChiemgaustraÃe 50%'

select      address
from        Directory
where       street like N'%Ã¼%'
```

Is there a query I can run to identify and replace these characters?

I must clarify that most of the data was imported correctly, in fact I believe the strange characters were already part of the original data.

Also, I think I can export the data to a text file, replace the characters and re-import, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it directly in sql.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try running your query with COLLATION (that allows accent sensitive).

Comment: I assume the data is nvarchar?

Comment: @Frisbee - Yes, it is nvarchar.

Comment: @FutbolFan - It almost worked but for some reason it wouldn't work Ã. Not sure what was going on. Thanks for the suggestion, it worked for 90% of the symbols I needed to fix.

Comment: So those characters can be one created different ways.  You may need to look the hex.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it fix using only sql.

FutbolFa suggestion worked for the most part but there were a couple of symbols, in particular "Ã" that wasn't picked up by any query a tried. I ended up exporting the data to a text file and replacing the symbols there. Then I just re-imported the info.